# Chances of getting approved for B2 US VISA

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, lebanese-citizens

I was hoping someone can help me here and let me know what my chances are to get approved a US Tourist Visa to visit my two sisters, nephews and nieces.

- I am 42 years old (female)
- I am married (20 years of marriage to the same person)
- I have three kids 1. 6 year old, 1. 12 year old and one 14 year old.
- I received my bachelors in education 15+ years ago and have always kept each job I had for at least 7 years.
- I worked for 12 years as a teacher with special education students
- 5 years ago, I received a new offer job for teaching special education kids for the blind and deaf and have been employee with them since then. I am one of the three teachers only as they do not hire anyone else since this is my expertise, I excel at it and truly enjoy my job.
- As many know, during the summer we have a summer break since the school is closed and I want to visit two of my sisters, nephews and nieces for one month since my sister wants to sponsor my trip (she is purchasing the airline tickets for me and my daughter and we are staying at her house and she is expensing our whole trip).
- Me and my kids (including my daughter who is coming with) have traveled to Turkey, Cyrpus and Greece twice within the last 3 years. We have received the schengan visa twice with no problem and we have always entered back within our time frame.
- My job has given my a paper for how long I have been employed, and how I will return back as this is a summer trip and the school is closed so I am not taking a leave. I don’t make a lot of money but average for my position and it’s been a stable job all my life.
- My daughter 6 years old will be traveling with me but my two boys will be staying here with their dad since they have a summer camp trip and they want to attend it and my husband can not leave work for that long.
- We fully own and paid off our property which is in a very nice area and has a nice/big value
- I have two vehicle’s; one, that I have paid off and one I am currently paying and 70% almost done paying.
- I have a mother who lives in my country, my 6 brothers and 3 sisters. My mother had a green card to the USA but she ended up coming back after a few months of visiting (6 years ago) as she didn’t like the USA.
- I only have two sisters in the USA and 3 nephew and nieces that I have not seen in 10+ years. My whole family is here in my country including my other two kids and husband who I will be leaving for less than a month to just visit my sister.
- My sister and her husband work for the government and has wrote me a sponsorship letter with multiple details and including a higher president in her government field to also vouch for me.
- Me and my daughter are only looking to go for about 30 days as I have to return and a week after returning I have to set up my class room for two weeks before the new school year starts.

I am just trying to go to visit my two sisters and nephew and nieces with my youngest daughter. I will be coming back a month before the school year starts to prepare my class room. I am leaving my husband, property, two children, 6 brothers, 3 sisters, my degree, vehicle, and etc. to show how much I have here to come back to. I have no intentions to stay as you can see all my family is in my home country including the love of my life (husband) and two other kids (from same husband).

What do you think my approval odds are? My sister is completely sponsoring this whole trip from booking our flights, every dollar to accommodation. I have never applied for a US visa and I am very worried and want to know what you think? I have prepared multiple documents to bring with me to the interview, so please let me know what you recommend me bringing. (I’m bringing sponsor paper, employment paper, my children’s birth certificates (even the two that aren’t coming with), my degree, bank statement and official ties to my country.

Comment: We could only guess, but sounds like you have plenty of ties to your home country.

Answer (score 0):

As a Lebanese citizen, your [adjusted refusal rate](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/Non-Immigrant-Statistics/RefusalRates/FY18.pdf) is 25.22%.

This **crudely** means the chances of approval are about 75% for the **average** Lebanese citizen applicant. We cannot conclude anything about you specifically.

Comment: Just looking for a guess on approval odds. Not taking words for granted :)